# Qt 6.6 Camera supported features

Tags: camera, qml, qt6

I'm trying to get the features that my camera support but I only receive, from this function, **0** as result:

```
void CameraInfoBridge::check(QCamera *camera) {
    qDebug() << "Features: " << camera->supportedFeatures();
}
```

I'm developing on windows 10 and I have the same result using:

- intregrated camera
- 2 other camera module
  is there something I miss?
  I guess it is rather weird that QT does not support any functions

I tried to read the [supportedFeatures](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#supportedFeatures-prop) property and I expect an int not equal to 0.

Comment: Can you check what `isAvailable()` is returning? If you look into the source code of `QCamera::supportedFeatures()` you can see that, if `d->control` isn't available it return `0x0`:  `return d->control ? d->control->supportedFeatures() : QCamera::Features{};`.

Comment: I did as you suggested: 
`qDebug() << "isAvailable: " << camera->isAvailable();`
and I received "True". Indeed I can use the camera in my qml app, I'm just trying to use some other Qml Camera class functions like zoom, whitebalance, ecc... so I'm quite sure that the camera is working.